# Which strategy about connection management should we use when developing an application?

Tags: database-connection

Which use of connection management is better while developing a windows based application which uses a Database as its data store? What about web-based applications?

1. when user loads the first form of an application, the global
   connection opens and on closing the last form of the application 
   the connection closes and disposes.
2. for each form within the application, there is a local connection
   (form scope) and when user wants to perform an operation like
   insert, update, delete, search, ... the application uses the
   connection and by unloading the form the connection also closes and
   disposes.
3. for every operation within a form of an application, there is a
   local connection (procedure scope) and when user wants to perform
   an operation like insert, update, delete, search, ... the
   application uses procedure connection and at the end of every
   procedure within the form, the connection also closes and disposes.

Comment: is the database on the same machine, or is the application connecting to the database remotely? this makes a big difference.

Comment: @ken: The second one: DB is on a remote machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with **#3**

*You should try to only ever keep connections open for just as long as is required.*

Also have a look at

- [Understanding Connection Pooling](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsdaf/ConnPooling07262006093645AM/ConnPooling.aspx)
- [SQL Server Connection Pooling
  (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

> Connecting to a database server
>   typically consists of several
>   time-consuming steps. A physical
>   channel such as a socket or a named
>   pipe must be established, the initial
>   handshake with the server must occur,
>   the connection string information must
>   be parsed, the connection must be
>   authenticated by the server, checks
>   must be run for enlisting in the
>   current transaction, and so on.
>
> In practice, most applications use
>   only one or a few different
>   configurations for connections. This
>   means that during application
>   execution, many identical connections
>   will be repeatedly opened and closed.
>   To minimize the cost of opening
>   connections, ADO.NET uses an
>   optimization technique called
>   connection pooling.
>
> Connection pooling reduces the number
>   of times that new connections must be
>   opened. The pooler maintains ownership
>   of the physical connection. It manages
>   connections by keeping alive a set of
>   active connections for each given
>   connection configuration. Whenever a
>   user calls Open on a connection, the
>   pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled
>   connection is available, it returns it
>   to the caller instead of opening a new
>   connection. When the application calls
>   Close on the connection, the pooler
>   returns it to the pooled set of active
>   connections instead of closing it.
>   Once the connection is returned to the
>   pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.

Comment: It seems this is a Windows-based (GUI?) application. If so, there's probably only going to be one user-interaction process going on at once, and I don't see how connection pooling would be at all useful.
Moreover, it sounds like you're proposing to maximize the overhead of the application in the name of keeping connections open only for a very short amount of time. This tradeoff does not sound worthwhile to me, without any further knowledge of particular constraints.

Comment: I do recall this line from the question : *What about web-based applications?*

Comment: @Astander: Oops! I missed that totally! (Sorry.) And aside from that, even for the GUI apps, I realize I'm being a bit too user-form-centric in my thinking. If you want different parts of the application to access the database at once (perhaps to update status indicators while the user is using a form) then by all means DO use connection pooling. Aside from that, though, my gut instinct is that opening and closing connections is more overhead than the alternative, so avoid it when possible.

Comment: it depends if the database is local or if it shared on a server between many different clients. it's bad for the user (and adds load to the server) if connections are being opened and closed all the time. OTOH, if many different clients are hanging on to connections but not doing anything with them, then server resources are being wasted. If a local connection pool is used, then it should be configured to release connections after an idle period.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad question. But usually, for any database server and application environment, opening and keeping a new connection is an expensive operation. That's why you definitely don't want to open multiple connections from a single client, and should stick to process-scope for connections.

In a desktop application using a database server, strategy for handling it's *single* connection depends a lot on the DB usage pattern. Say, if the app reads or writes something a lot within 5 minutes, and then just does nothing with the DB for hours, it makes no sense to keep the connection open all the time (assuming there are many other clients). You may introduce some kind of time-out for closing a connection.

The Web server situation depends a lot on the used technology. Say, in PHP every request is a "fresh start" WRT database connection. You open and close a connection for each mouse click. While popular Java application servers have DB connections pool, reusing the same connection instances for many HTTP request handling threads.